# Java/Eclipse: Exception handler - Printing a message And a Variable in a single Println Line

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a little problem that i need help with.

For this assignment (Lesson 12 HW9) name NumberFormatException,I had to do the following below

"Calculator.java, is a simple command-line calculator. Note that the program terminates if any operand is nonnumeric. Write a program with an exception handler that deals with nonnumeric operands. Your program should display a message that informs the user of the wrong operand before exiting (see the figure shown below)."

```
c:\exercise>java Exercise12_01 "4 + 5"

4 + 5 = 9

c:\exercise>java Exercise12_01 "4 - 5"

4 - 5 = -1

c:\exercise>java Exercise12_01 "4x - 5"

Wrong Input: 4x
```

SO all the math parts of the coding is finished, correct, and works, the only part I cant seem to figure out is:
" display a message that informs the user of the wrong operand before exiting" Wrong Input: **4x**. I need to know what I can do to show not only the error message, but the error input as well. the part where it show the error message to the user is at the end of the code at

```
    catch(InputMismatchException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Bad input, please correct your operard."); 
    } //need to add the input error as well
```

here the full code, thank you

```js
import java.util.*;
public class FillZerosOnes {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 
 Scanner Read = new Scanner(System.in);
 Random randNum = new Random();
 int n;
 int rowCount, columnCount;
 int maxrowCount, maxcolumnCount;
 ArrayList<Integer> Rows = new ArrayList(),Columns = new ArrayList();
 int[][] matrix;
 
 System.out.println("Enter the array size n: ");
 n = Read.nextInt();
 
 matrix = new int[n][n];
 
 System.out.println("The random array size : ");
 
 
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
 
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
 matrix[i][j] = randNum.nextInt(2);//choose the number above 1 for the number you want to be less then
 //if I want 0 & 1, out 2
 
 System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
  }
  System.out.println();

 
 
 
 
 }
 
 columnCount = 0;
 maxrowCount= 0;
 maxcolumnCount =0;
 
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  rowCount =0; 
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
   if (matrix[i][j] ==1 )
   {
    rowCount++;
   }
  }
  if (rowCount > maxrowCount )
  {
   maxrowCount = rowCount;
   Rows.removeAll(Rows); // or Rows = new Arraylist();
   Rows.add(i);
  }
  else if (rowCount == maxrowCount)
  {
   Rows.add(i);
  } 
 }
 //copy and paste
 for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
 {
  columnCount =0; 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
   if (matrix[i][j] ==1 )
   {
    columnCount++;
   }
  }
  if (columnCount > maxcolumnCount )
  {
   maxcolumnCount = columnCount;
   Columns.removeAll(Columns); // or Rows = new Arraylist();
   Columns.add(j);
  }
  else if (columnCount == maxcolumnCount)
  {
   Columns.add(j);
  } 
 } //end paste
 
 
 System.out.print("Largest row indices: ");
 for (int i = 0; i < Rows.size(); i++)
 {
  System.out.print(Rows.get(i));
 }
 

 System.out.printf("\nLargest column indices: ");
 for (int i = 0; i < Columns.size(); i++)
 {
  System.out.print(Columns.get(i));
 }
}
}
```

Comment: this is the wrong code i out in please ignore

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("text to show"+variable);

Comment: the problem is that the User  Might get only "N" or "V" wrong, and i dont know how to put only the Variable that is wrong while leaving the other variable alone.

Answer (score 0):

I usually log the stack trace on exception:

```
System.out.println("Bad input, please correct your operand." + ex.getMessage());
```

But you can also print out your variables in a similar manner:

```
System.out.println("Bad input, please correct your operands: " + n + ", " + v);
```